# Are "好饱了" and "好包了" both correct?

Tags: characters, phrase, spelling

"好饱了" and "好包了" both seem to be used to mean "I'm full".

I'm pretty sure that "好饱了" is definitely correct but they both get lots of Google hits and if I combine the search with the English "full" they are about equally popular.

So is "好包了" also correct or is it a common spelling mistake?

Comment: 包 means bun like xiao longbao (soup dumplings) 饱 means full like 我饱了wo bao le (I'm full) sorry on mobile or would format this better as an answer

Comment: There is no expression like "好包了" in Chinese I'm afraid.

Comment: If a Chinese native speaker says "我吃得好包了", I would consider he is feeling his belly "encases (包)" his stomach, which means he is full. I am not sure if it is from some dialect.

Comment: @Stan No such expression either, I'm afraid. It's like holding a potato and call it tomato.

Comment: @Xephon I did have heard of "吃得好bāo了" for several times from some native speakers. As a native speaker I felt it was exactly "好包了", just like a similar but much more popular expression "我吃得好撑了", which also uses a verb-like adjective (撑) to describe how full he is. Of course, I was not totally sure because I didn't ask them for the exact character. However I think a language should not be a list of dead rules, sometimes novel metaphors even misuses would make it lively and interesting :-)

Comment: @Stan If we include dialects, then yes, this is indeed possibly valid. I remember hearing some friends from south-west area saying something similar. They confirmed it is from their dialect. If we are talking about Mandarin, no, this is not a valid sentence. Just to clear what I meant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, "好包了" does not mean "I'm full".

You may see "...打好包了..." in the Google hits. It refers to "have made something into a package.

If your friend say "这顿饭我包了". That means your friend will get the bill, and you don't pay the bill.

You will see "7天包退" on some goods's package, that means "7 days to cancel purchase for non-faulty goods".

And "他们的村庄被敌人包围了" refers to "Their village was surround by the enemy."

Comment: Ah, good eye. Forgot that 好包了 could be part of something preceeding it. I'd be shocked if that ever passed for "stomach being full".

Answer (score 4):

There is no expression "好包了".

Actually, "好饱了" is also a strange spelling, since we usually use "我吃饱了" to express "I am full".

Comment: I learned "好饱了" from one of the flashcard courses on memrise.com - I'm not sure where its author got it from. (As for the other spelling, I think that's what my IME generated when I typed the pinyin, but it turned out to have Google hits too.)

Comment: @hippietrail Such expression does exist in Cantonese. Certain region from Fujian may use such expression as some of my relatives from that area say in such manner sometime. It is not universal in Chinese dialect though. It is not a correct expression in Mandarin at all.

Comment: It does *seem to* get 1.3 million Google hits. Almost all in China and almost none in Taiwan. Anyway, here are the links to where I found it on memrise: [1](http://www.memrise.com/course/251/restaurant-survival/3/), [2](http://www.memrise.com/course/251/restaurant-survival/12/), [3](http://www.memrise.com/mem/1678657/hao-baole-full-done-eating/).

Comment: I can confirm that another of my teaching materials, a book published in Taiwan, gives "吃饱了".

Comment: @hippietrail I found memrise.com's Chinese courses pretty awful, and stopped using it.

Comment: @Ming: Memrise doesn't make the courses, its users make the courses. So if one course made by one user is bad it doesn't mean that all courses made by all users are bad. And of course you can make your own course and just use it as your private flashcard tool. You can also leave a comment on any item to question it. I haven't received responses to any of my comments yet though.

Comment: @hippietrail yep I know, just saying that the ones I started were pretty awful.